# Create GeoDataFrame polygon geometry from coordinates list of lists

Tags: python, geopandas

My current dataframe (`clean_geoms`) contains two columns (`field_geom_type`, `field_coords`) that I want to convert to a single geometry (GeoSeries)

This is a representative sample of my data:

```
print(clean_geoms.field_geom_type.iloc[0])
print(clean_geoms.field_coords.iloc[0])

Polygon
[[[-96.568927, 46.769008], [-96.5689454, 46.7705433], [-96.5726564, 46.7705222], [-96.572638, 46.7689868], [-96.568927, 46.769008]]]
```

What is the best way to unpack this list so that it can be converted into geometry?

Comment: A list of lists of lists already is the best way to convert *any* geometry (including multi-part geometries and polygons with sub-parts)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using built-in `eval` method is handful in this situation.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

clean_geoms = pd.DataFrame([["Polygon", "[[[-96.568927, 46.769008], [-96.5689454, 46.7705433], [-96.5726564, 46.7705222], [-96.572638, 46.7689868], [-96.568927, 46.769008]]]"]],
                           columns=["field_geom_type", "field_coords"])
print(clean_geoms)

# OUTPUT
#    field_geom_type  field_coords
# 0  Polygon          [[[-96.568927, 46.769008], [-96.5689454, 46.77...


data = Polygon(eval(clean_geoms.field_coords.iloc[0])[0])
gdf = gpd.GeoSeries(data)
print(gdf)

# OUTPUT
# 0    POLYGON ((-96.56893 46.76901, -96.56895 46.770...
# dtype: geometry
```